# Spring Boot plugin requires Gradle 4.10 or later. The current version is Gradle 4.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a Spring Gradle project. I'm trying to make a build using `gradle build` command. But getting below error :

```
* Where:
Build file 'F:\MyProjectName\build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.2.2.RELEASE']
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.springframework.boot']
   > Spring Boot plugin requires Gradle 4.10 or later. The current version is Gradle 4.1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

But I'm already using I'm using **gradle-5.6.4**. and also tried latest **gradle-6.0.1-bin** but getting same error.

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Wed Dec 04 12:51:57 IST 2019
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:1.0.7.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.4.0.RELEASE'
    implementation 'de.mkammerer:argon2-jvm:2.6'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

jar {
    enabled true
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

How to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is with this link: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip` ?

Comment: This is my default `gradle-wrapper.properties` file and `distributionUrl`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're using the command `gradle build`, then you're not using the wrapper, and thus not using the version of gradle configured in the wrapper properties. You're using the global gradle version installed on your machine.

To use the gradle wrapper, use

```
./gradlew build
```

or, on Windows

```
.\gradlew.bat build
```

in your project root folder.

[Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html).

Comment: That's a completely different issue. Remove your `jar { enabled true }` section.

Comment: Solved my issue using `./gradlew bootJar`    :)

Comment: @Victory you should then accept this answer, which is THE good answer ;)

Answer (score 29):

1. Open File `gradle-wrapper.properties`
2. You will find `distributionUrl` with value something like `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-bin.zip`
3. Change the **gradle version to greater than 4.10** , as I have **5.6.2**

Note, this will upgrade the locally scoped gradle version.  (As opposed to the system wide gradle install)
 You will have to use the gradlew(rapper) to invoke.

For example (on linux based)

./gradlew  build

I am guessing it would be similar on windows

```
.\gradlew.bat build
```

You CANNOT use

```
gradle build
```

because that will call the machine-scoped version (which will be the old version probably)

Full locally scoped output below:

```
./gradlew  build

Welcome to Gradle 5.6.2!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Incremental Groovy compilation
 - Groovy compile avoidance
 - Test fixtures for Java projects
 - Manage plugin versions via settings script
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the cause was an old `settings.gradle` residing in the project's completely unrelated parent(!) directory.

Answer (score 0):

In my case some other project in the same workspace ".settings/org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs" file is having below property

```
gradle.user.home=C\:/Gradle/gradle-6.7/bin(old version)
```

replaced with the following:

```
gradle.user.home=C\:/Gradle/gradle-7.3.2/bin(new version)
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradle 5.6.3 support the spring boot version till 2.4.13

**Gradle**  *Spring Boot*(max version suported)
5.6.3        2.4.13